# Completing a Graph in Scheme

Tags: recursion, graph, scheme

For the record, this is part of a homework assignment, but I have already implemented a solution. I am simply wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Background: I am asked to write a procedure, (complete ls), that takes a list of elements and creates a fully connected graph from them, i.e. complete. I am able to write helper functions to assist in my solution.

A sample graph is defined as `'((a (b c)) (b (a c)))`. Where the `car` of each sub-list is a vertex and the `cdr` of each sub-list is a list of vertices that vertex is connected to.

For example:

```
(complete? '((a (b c)) (b (a c)) (c (a b)))) => #t
(complete? '((a (b)) (b (a c)) (c ()))) => #f
```

My working solution:

```
(define (complete ls)
    (helpComplete ls ls)
)

(define (helpComplete origLst ls)
  (if (null? ls)
    '()
    (cons
      (list
        (car ls)
        (remove-first (car ls) origLst))
      (helpComplete origLst (cdr ls)))))

(define (remove-first element ls)
  (cond
    [(null? ls) '()]
    [(eqv? element (car ls)) (cdr ls)]
    [else (cons (car ls) (remove-first element (cdr ls)))]
  ))
```

I am not allowed to change the inputs for the `complete` procedure, as our grading server is expecting it to look like it is now. I am also not allowed to use and `!` procedures. We are running Petite Chez Scheme Version 8, if anyone cares.

The above code does work, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it?

Comment: Sure it works? `origList` is spelled differently and it doesn't seem like you are returning a #f for your second example.

Comment: You don't need to return #f. `complete?` is a predicate `complete` is a procedure to construct a complete graph.

Comment: " have already implemented a solution. I am simply wondering if there is a better way to do it." This would probably be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com, then.

Answer (score 0):

This simpler version should work.

I removed the third clause from the checks in `remove-first` since it will never be reached under the use case.

```
(define (complete ls)

  (define (remove-first element in)
    (if (eqv? element (car in))
      (cdr in)
      (cons (car in) (remove-first element (cdr in)))))

  (map (lambda (item) (list item (remove-first item ls))) ls)
)
```